# How to clip an image/layer like photoshop to an animation that has a transparent background in Premier pro?

Tags: video, editing, premiere-pro, compositing, clipping

Good day! I'm new to premiere pro, and here is my issue. I have an animation/sequence I'm currently compositing in premiere pro that has a transparent background and I forgot to add shadows on it, that it is supposed to look like it enters a tunnel, and I don't want to re-render my animation just for that. Is there a way to clip an image that acts like a shadow onto the animation/sequence like clipping layers in photoshop? I already tried using track matte but it only works for videos that are going to be clipped on a text/image/shape, not images that are the ones gonna clip onto a video.

Example using Photoshop:
Assume the train is moving, but the shadow is static.
[image]